# Deactivate click-Event for last column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

On my js I set a click-Event for each table-row.
This works fine atm.
I try to remove the click-Event just for the last column of this table, but it doesn't work.

Do you have an idea why? Is the selector right or do I have to select more than just the last-child of td?

```
function addRowHandlers() {
var table = document.getElementById("klauselliste");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = table.rows[i];
    var createClickHandler =
        function (row) {
            return function () {
                var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                var name = cell.innerHTML;
                window.location.href = '/Klausel/Detail?Name=' + name.trim();
            };
        };

    currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
}



// Code Snippet
addRowHandlers();
$("td:last-child").unbind("click");
// Code Snippet
```

Comment: Try `$("td").last().off("click");`. But I'm not sure, if you can unbind html events with jQuery, when not created by jQuery. Why do you create it the 'html way' but unset it with jQuery?

Comment: At least use `rows.length - 1` ...  But instead of all this bunch of code, just use jQuery to bind relevant click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your code as "pure jQuery". Less code, same effort. Note the `:not(:last-child)`, it will select all `td` of a row, execpt the last.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    $("table#klauselliste tr td:not(:last-child)").click(function() {
        var name = $("td:eq(0)", $(this).parent()).html();
        window.location.href = '/Klausel/Detail?Name=' + name.trim();
    });
}
```

See here for an working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wuhtt7sc/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answere. If i do it like this, ill get an error "Klausel.js:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". I think its cause the table isnt completly loaded yet.

Comment: No, this means, that jQuery is not correctly loaded/included at this point. Check this fist. And then make sure you call your code in a jQuery ready state, like: `$(function() { /* your actions here*/ });`, like in my fiddle.

Comment: Awesome it worked! JQuery is getting included by a bundle in Visual Studio but way to late imo ^^ Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.find()` to locate the last element on your table.

```
$('#klauselliste tr').find('td:last').on('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: If you do so, why so complicated? `$('#klauselliste tr td:last').off("click");` and done.

Comment: You're right @eisbehr. Thanks for correcting me. =)